# Threads getting blocked while opening a connection using apache commons

Tags: java, apache-commons, blocked-threads

from my application, many threads are trying to get a connection from oracle but I am seeing only one thread is able to get connection at a time. till this thread gets connection, other threads are blocked which is causing slowness in application. I need help determining why other threads are getting blocked. am i running out of connections than the available connections in pool?

Thread holding the lock.

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.LocalXAConnectionFactory.createConnection(LocalXAConnectionFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.PoolableManagedConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableManagedConnectionFactory.java:64)

- locked <0x0000000641e88660> (a org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.PoolableManagedConnectionFactory)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.ManagedConnection.updateTransactionStatus(ManagedConnection.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.ManagedConnection.<init>(ManagedConnection.java:59)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.ManagedDataSource.getConnection(ManagedDataSource.java:81)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
    at com.manh.jdbc.ScopeDataSource.getConnection(ScopeDataSource.java:79)


Thread waiting for lock on PoolableManagedConnectionFactory

"pool-38-thread-5389" #267084 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00002b6b66541800 nid=0x18dcf waiting for monitor entry [0x00002b6bfd047000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.PoolableManagedConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableManagedConnectionFactory.java:64)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000641e88660> (a org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.PoolableManagedConnectionFactory)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.ManagedConnection.updateTransactionStatus(ManagedConnection.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.ManagedConnection.<init>(ManagedConnection.java:59)
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to commit or close your connections?

Comment: I am not sure on connection leaks as my application is very vast, Do you think connection pool has exhausted due to connection leaks in applications by looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Definitely. It isn't blocked opening a connection, it is blocked on some monitor in the pool, which suggests it's waiting for a connection to be freed. Apache DBCP has some leak detection tools in it. Use them.

Comment: Can you add the configuration for your connection pool, the code that uses the pool and how many threads are utilizing the pool concurrently.